# Converting part of a string to upper case in CMake

Tags: regex, cmake, capitalization

Is there a convenient way to transform a string that is all lower case so that the first character is upper case?

I currently have a working solution:

```
#PROTO_NAME is the lower-case string
string(SUBSTRING ${PROTO_NAME} 0 1 FIRST_LETTER)
string(TOUPPER ${FIRST_LETTER} FIRST_LETTER)
string(REGEX REPLACE "^.(.*)" "${FIRST_LETTER}\\1" PROTO_NAME_CAP "${PROTO_NAME}")
```

The result is in the `PROTO_NAME_CAP` variable. Is there a simpler or more convenient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no built-in solution for this in CMake. You can only hide your code behind a function if you want to make things more readable.